# Why normals lines not coming from faces

Tags: faces, normals

[image: Why do the normals line display look like this? Face orientation seems to be correct but the lines aren't coming from the faces.]

Why do the normals line display look like this? Face orientation seems to be correct but the lines aren't coming from the faces.

Comment: Based on your image there not a lot that I can see qualitatively abnormal, but if you can share your blend file (https://blend-exchange.com/) we may be better able to help you.

Comment: Can you at least show your viewport overlay settings? Also, you've got `In Front` active, this will show your model over the top of all the normal lines.

Comment: It is as @Psyonic says, you have _In Front_ enabled in the _Viewport Display_ > _Show_ settings, that's why the normals are hidden by the mesh.

Comment: Deactivate "In Front" https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hXGF.png

Comment: @Psyonic YES! Thank you.  "In Front" was the culprit. Y'all are great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have uncovered a bug.. ( at least, on my system )

I was going to suggest just toggling 'On Cage' on your Mirror modifier

[image]

.. but it looks as though you have it on already..

However, when I do that on a model displaying Vertex and Face Normals (in Cyan), this is what I get:

[image]

the Vertex Normals are correctly displayed, but the Face Normals look to be having some trouble.

Comment: Thanks...the problem was I had "In Front" turned on under viewport display

Comment: @Vicki thought so... out of interest, do you see your Face Normals (ahem) normally?

Comment: That is a weird one... Happens on my system too

Comment: @Psyonic  might report .. haven't looked for dupes yet. Your system / version ?

Comment: Linux 5.19.11-200.fc36.x86_64  - Blender 3.5.0